# How to center a DIV with unknown size horizontaly and vertically on screen

Tags: html, css, layout, alignment

I need to center a DIV on center off screen, both horizontally and vertically, I don't know the DIV size, and the div is `position:fixed;`.

This negative margin trick does not work, because I don't know the div size.
`top:50%; left:50%; magin-top:-100; margin-left:-100;`

The `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` does not work because doesn't work with `position:fixed;` and `margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto;` also does not vertically center;

I found that this method: `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` don't work ether;

I know how to do this with JavaScript using getComputedStyle to get the div content size, and do the math to fix it position, but I want a pure CSS solution, because I don't want to trigger a JS every time my div content changes.

Comment: And how's your `div` content changing? Through plain CSS animation or JavaScript animations?

Comment: @balexandre there's no animation, content changes via Ajax

Answer (score 4):

You can vertically center a box with an unknown height with the help of css tables. The height of the box is determined by its contents. See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tR5ZN/) that uses the **position: fixed** property for the box. The box's **width is set** as well.

And this is the workaround for IE <= 7:

```
#table {
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#container {
  display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#IEcenter {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#container * {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Does this meet your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with positions, transform properties will be helpful here.

You just have to add the below properties to the element which has to centered,

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%);
```

Please remove the extra margin and padding added to the element.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4kxDd/) (height is unknown, width is set).

You can use css tables (in this example html is the table whereas body is a table-cell). Markup:

```
<body>

    <div id="container">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffea00;
  border: 2px solid #ff9800;
}
```

Do you need a workaround for IE <=7 (since IE <=7 doesn't know about table | table-cell)?

Comment: I just need compilant browsers support. Changing html and body styles don't mess with other inline content on the page, or it work with a div wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? It also uses the `display: table-cell` but it requires 2 div tags to work... the parent tag having a `display: table` style specified.

NB: I added `z-index:-1;` to the centerbase class. You may want to tweak this based on your design.

```
<style>
.centerbase{
    display: table; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
.centerpane{
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<div class="centerbase">
    <div class="centerpane">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" />
    </div>
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</div>
```

If you need to add text that is not aligned center within the centerpane, you can add another div inside the centerpane and specify the style as something like: `text-align:left; width:400px; margin:0px auto;` You will have to specify a width for this additional div.